# Debian PowerBook G4 WiFi Driver

Tags: debian, apt, xfce, wifi, powerpc

How do I get wifi to work on my powerbook g4 with xfce debian? I have tried `sudo apt-get install bcm43xx-fwcutter` but it comes up with `E: Unable to locate package bcm43xx-fwcutter`. What do I do?

Comment: The package name is `b43-fwcutter`, as you can see searching with `apt-cache search --names-only fwcutter`

Comment: @enzotib It can't locate that either.

Comment: It is in `contrib` archive, have you put it in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: how do i put it in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: In that file, add the word `contrib`, after the word `main` that should already be there.

Comment: @enzotib here is my `/etc/apt/sources.list`: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/05xc

Answer (score 2):

I finally got my Wireless card working in Powerbook G4 Aluminum 1.25Ghz laptop running Debian 7.5.0 Wheezy.

1) go to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, add 'contrib' and 'non-free' behind every line ( it's an overkill but I don't know what I am doing )

Here is part of my file:

```
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.5.0 _Wheezy_ - Official powerpc DVD Binary-1 20140426-14:34]/ wheezy contrib main non-free

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

a) then type this at your terminal:

```
apt-get update
```

2) type in a terminal to find your wireless card model number:

```
lspci | grep -i wireless
```

Mine showed

```
$ lspci | grep -i wireless
0001:10:12.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4306 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 02)
```

3) go [the bcm43xx on the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/bcm43xx). From last step, because my version is BCM4306 (rev 02), I have to choose

```
apt-get install firmware-b43legacy-installer
```

For devices with a BCM4306 revision 3, BCM4311, BCM4318, BCM4321 or BCM4322 chip, install firmware-b43-installer:

```
apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

For devices with a BCM4312 LP-PHY chip (PCI ID 14E4:4315), install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer:

```
apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

4) rebooted and wireless card now has non-free firmware working. Unfortunately it's non-free. I don't know other method.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is extremely old, but here is a generic solution to get wifi working on any linux distribution with a somewhat modern kernel (tested woth 5.4) on many power macs (tested with a PowerBook G4 with airport):

- check dmesg after boot and search for b43
- it will tell you which firmware files are missing. You can extract them using the fwcutter tool, or you can find them by searching online for the filenames on github repos. I don't think redistributing them like that is legal so I won't link them.
- place the files in /lib/firmware/b43, creating the directory if needed
- reboot, if it still doesn't work check dmesg again, possibly you need to add more files.
- repeat until it works

This worked for me on Adlie Linux and also works for other devices requiring proprietary firmware, such as radeon graphics.
There is also b43-open, I didn't test it yet, but the name implies that it's an open firmware and dmesg reports that it's also an option. Please leave a comment if that workes for you as well.